# How to check if none of checkboxes is selected in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android project. I have 3 pages in which each page contains some decription and below the desciption 5 to 8 checkboxes. I kept the next button at the top of each page. I am storing the selected check box id's in an arraylist. i.e if I check the checkbox the id will be stored in the arraylist and if I uncheck the checkbox the id will be deleted from the arraylist. (I need the selected checkboxes fo further pages and hence this task).  **If none of the checkbox is selected and next button is clicked i want to display an alert saying that "Please select atleast one". How to check if none of the checkbox is selected and how to display an alert box?** Please help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your `ArrayList` of IDs and check if each box is checked.

```
boolean isChecked = false;
for (int id : yourArrayOfIds) {
    if (((CheckBox) findViewById(id)).isChecked()) {
        isChecked = true;
        break;
    }
}
// If isChecked==true, a box is checked.
```

You may also want to check if the [`CheckBox`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) object is `null` before using `isChecked()`. This is just a rudimentary example.

To show your alert, use something like [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Show-Alert-Dialog-in-Android). There are lots of other tutorials and [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) as well.